# Can I have pagination, ordering, column selection and filtering in raw data table in a Tableau view?

Tags: pagination, filtering, tableau-api, raw-data

When I click a bar in a bar chart or a slice in a pie chart I am able to see a table with the underlying raw data. This is very useful, but is it possible to achieve the following functionalities?

1. Pagination. I would like my users to be able to view all the data page by page in the browser rather than having to download a csv file.
2. Dynamic ordering. That is when you click a column to indicate that you would like to sort the rows by values in that column and you choose ascending or descending order.
3. Column selection. I would like to be able to either let users select what columns to display or at least define them upfront for raw data for a given chart.
4. Filtering. Can I dynamically add filters to columns as I browse the raw data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have any of that in raw data view, it is more of a developer view rather than a viz user view.
 What you can do to get some of the functionality is to build a separate worksheet with data table and use actions to navigate there from your chart.